# Jikes rvm runtime err "Could not find the class java.util.Scanner"

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jikes

When I used Jikes rvm to run my program "GenRegex.class",

```
jikesrvm-3.1.2/dist/production_x86_64-linux/rvm GenRegex grammars/cfg_nse.g
```

I got the runtime err:

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not find the class java.util.Scanner:
        java.util.Scanner
   at java.lang.Error.(Error.java:81)
   at java.lang.LinkageError.(LinkageError.java:72)
   at java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.(NoClassDefFoundError.java:74)
   at org.jikesrvm.classloader.TypeReference.resolveInternal(TypeReference.java:813)
   at org.jikesrvm.classloader.TypeReference.resolve(TypeReference.java:799)
   at org.jikesrvm.runtime.RuntimeEntrypoints.unresolvedNewScalar(RuntimeEntrypoints.java:264)
   at GenRegex.genRule(GenRegex.java:12)
   at GenRegex.main(GenRegex.java:1133)
```

Below is my code

```
   1 import java.util.*;
   2 import java.io.*;
   3 
   4 public class GenRegex{
   5 
   6   Rule[] genRule(String fileName) throws IOException
   7   {
   8     String line = "";
   9     String str = "";
  10     ArrayList ruleList = new ArrayList();
  11     Rule[] ruleArray;
  12     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Even after I add a line "import java.util.Scanner;" I still got this err. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with Jikes.  Is it possible you need to include some "standard" java library in your project manually (via your GUI)?  Often it is a library/dependency issue for me when I get a runtime NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Maybe the problem comes from the GNU Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found some disappointing information **"java.util.Scanner is unimplemented"** in Jikes RVM, at least in version 3.0.1.

See this link: http://lwn.net/Articles/303938/

```
Jikes RVM 3.0.1 released
...
** Bug 
* [RVM-172] - Failing DaCapo benchmarks on PPC 32 OS X 
* [RVM-288] - Assertion failure in inline oracle 
* [RVM-318] - java.util.Scanner is unimplemented  
...
```

For the current version 3.1.2, I'm unsure.